# Method invocation failed because [System.String] does not contain a method named 'saveasfile'

Tags: powershell, outlook

I have a powershell script which downloads outlook mail attachments.
But I recieve below error:

Method invocation failed because [System.String] does not contain a method named 'saveasfile'.

I have used below script

```
Add-Type -Assembly "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook"
$Outlook = New-Object -ComObject Outlook.Application
$Namespace = $Outlook.GetNameSpace("MAPI")
$inbox = $mapi.GetDefaultFolder(6)
$saveFilePath = "C:\temp\"
$subfolder = $inbox.Folders | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq “REPORTS”}

$mail = $subfolder.Items | Select-Object -Property Subject,SentOn,@{name="Attachments";expression={$_.Attachments|%{$_.DisplayName}}} | Where-Object{$_.attachments -match ".html" -and ($_.SentOn -gt '29-Oct-19 12:00:00 AM')} 

foreach ($email in $mail)
{
    if ($email.attachments.count -ge 1)
    {
        foreach ($attachment in $email.attachments)
        {
        $filename = $attachment.filename 
        $attachment.saveasfile((join-path $savefilepath $filename))
        }
    }
}
```

Please let me know how can I resolve this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Outlook's `Attachments` property's enumerator returns a `String` key, not an actual attachment object (this is why using an untyped or weakly-typed language like PowerShell for working with COM is a very bad idea).

While PowerShell *wants* to be used as a functional, pipelining language (which is a PITA to debug) - sometimes it's easier to use old-fashioned imperative code:

```
For( $i = 0; $i -le $email.Attachments.Count; $i++ ) {
    $attachment = $email.Attachments.Item( $i )
    $attachment.SaveAsFile( ( Join-Path $savefilepath $filename ) )
}
```

BTW, you don't need the `if ($email.attachments.count -ge 1)` statement because the `For( $i = 0; $i...` loop also checks the `.Attachments.Count` property too.

Comment: Can you provide a way through which i can download attachments from a particular folder. Because all over web this is the only script I can findi using COM. Please help me out

Comment: @EkanshSingh You can use the code in my answer with the rest of your existing code, just replace the body of the outer `foreach( $email in $mail )` loop.

Comment: Please help since I'm stuck with same error even after using loop in the way you mentioned

Comment: @EkanshSingh You won't get the same error with my code because my code won't have `$attachment` becoming a `String` value. If you are seeing the exact same error message then the error is coming from another line in the code, or you're running a different script file without realising it. What happens when you run the script inside PowerShell ISE's debugger?